# Randomly select an item from a list based on a class, repeat number of times based on different numbers

Tags: vba, excel

I am not familiar with using macro's, but I think that what I would like excel to perform is best handled with a macro. So I can use all the input you may have!

I have these headers;

ID  Tag Pen Sex Weight  Class   Inside range

With 450 rows of data. Based on the distribution of the weight data, I have in two other columns (class and number) the number of rows I want to select within each class. The selected rows must have the value "Yes" in the column "Inside range".

I want to randomly select the rows, based on the number needed for each class, and copy these rows to a new sheet. It sums up to 30 rows in the new sheet.

I hope you have a suggestion how to complete this action!

Comment: Would [this question / answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542617/non-repeating-random-number-generator) give you a good start to your macro? As far as I can tell you want to select 30 random, unique numbers between  1 and 450, and copy the corresponding rows to a different sheet?

Comment: Yes, but I do want to select a certain number for different classes based on the weight distribution. For example 2 for one class, 4 for another, etc. The number for the different classes is also indicated in the excel sheet.

Comment: So you want to select x random rows, which satisfy criteria  and z? The way I'd go about that would just be selecting a random row, check if it satisfied the criteria, and then move on to the next one until I had found enough. Of course, if the ranges are divided up well enough that you don't have to search all 450 rows, that'd be even better, but which such small data size the influence on performance should be negligible.

Answer (score 0):

can you try the following, you will need to add a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime library:

```
Const rowCount = 450
Public Sub copyRows() 
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer 
    Dim classes As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim source As Worksheet
    Dim colNumber As Integer
    Dim colClassName as Integer
    Dim colInsideRange As Integer
    Dim allSelected As Boolean
    Dim randomRow as Integer
    Dim sumRemaining as Integer
    allSelected = False
    Set source = Worksheets("YourWorksheetName")
    colClassName = 6 'this is the column number where class names are entered. I am assuming 6
    colNumber = 7 'this is the column number where number of rows to be selected are entered. I am assuming 7
    colInsideRange  = 8 'this is the column number where "Inside Range" values are entered. I am assuming 9
    For i = 2 to rowCount + 1 'assuming you have a header row
        classes(CStr(source.Cells(i, colClassName))) = CInt(source.cells(i, colNumber)
    Next i
    Do until allSelected 
        Randomize
        randomRow = Int ((Rnd * 450) + 2) 'assuming you have a header row, + 1 if you don't
        If classes(CStr(source.Cells(randomRow, colClassName))) = 0 Then
            With classes
                sumRemaining = 0
                For j = 1 to .Count - 1
                    sumRemaining = sumRemaining + .Items(j)
                    If sumRemaining > 0 Then Exit For
                Next j
                allSelected = (sumRemaining = 0)
            End With
        Else
            source.Cells(randomRow, colInsideRange) = "Yes"
            classes(CStr(source.Cells(randomRow, colClassName))) = classes(CStr(source.Cells(randomRow, colClassName))) - 1
        End If
    Loop
    'Enter your code to copy rows with "Inside Range" = "Yes"
End Sub
```

Sorry if there are some errors or typos, I wrote from my mobile phone.